# SEO with an iframe and a secondary domain

Tags: seo, iframe

Just a question, a client of the company I work for was

They run the SEO page on a new domain (they own it for the client) http://kunstplanten-decoratie.nl/kunst_vetplanten/ while the original page is located at: http://www.deco-trade.nl/index.php/kunstplanten/alle-planten.html

Below is the code they are using, they use an iframe to include the real domain.

Is this even allowed by SEO tactics and does the content of the iframe even get indexed?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>Kunst vetplanten | Deco Trade</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="De kunst vetplanten van Deco Trade zijn een mooi decoratiemiddel voor zowel thuis als op kantoor">
<meta name="keywords" content="Kunst vetplanten, KUNSTPLANTEN">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css.php">
</head>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Florist"><div id="wrap"><div id="body">
<h1>Kunst vetplanten</h1>
<p><img src="kunst_vetplanten.gif" alt="Kunst vetplanten | Deco Trade"><strong>Kunst vetplanten, KUNSTPLANTEN</strong></p>
<h3>De kunst vetplanten van Deco Trade zijn een mooi decoratiemiddel voor zowel thuis als op kantoor</h3>
<p>Deco Trade heeft een ruime sortering kunst vetplanten in verschillende maten. Een tweetal keuzes zijn de Crassula kunt vetplant en de Senecio kunst vetplant. De Crassula kunst vetplant is met zijn dikke diep groene bladeren en echte houten stammen een mooie vetplant voor op tafel of dressoir. Het model leent zich perfect voor presentatie in een luxe schaal, maar de Crassula laat zich ook goed combineren met een smalle hoge plantenbak.</p>
<p>De diameter van de kunst Crassula is ±45-50cm en de hoogte inclusief de binnenpot is ±70cm. Standaard wordt de kunstplant geleverd in een plastic binnenpot zodat deze eenvoudig in een sierpot te plaatsen is. De afgebeelde sierpotten kunnen los besteld worden. Tevens leverbaar in een kleine maat van 40cm.</p>
<p>De Senecio kunst vetplant, is met zijn vele blaadjes een leuke vetplant voor op tafel of in de vensterbank. Als enkel kunstplantje in een hoge sierpot, met meerdere op een rij, of in een luxe platte schaal, met deze kunst vetplant kun je perfect decoreren! De diameter van de Senecio kunstplant is ±30cm en de hoogte inclusief het binnenpotje is ±20cm. Standaard wordt het plantje geleverd in een 12cm plastic binnenpot zodat deze eenvoudig in een sierpot te plaatsen is. De afgebeelde sierpotten kunnen los besteld worden.</p>
<p class="centre"><a href="../kunst_buxusbal/" title="Kunst buxusbal">Kunst buxusbal</a> <a href="../kunstbuxusballen/" title="Kunstbuxusballen">Kunstbuxusballen</a> <a href="../kunstcactus/" title="Kunstcactus">Kunstcactus</a> <a href="../kunst_cactus/" title="Kunst cactus">Kunst cactus</a> <a href="../kunst_bloeiende_planten/" title="Kunst bloeiende planten">Kunst bloeiende planten</a> <a href="../buiten_kunst_planten/" title="Buiten kunst planten">Buiten kunst planten</a> <a href="../kunst_ficus/" title="Kunst Ficus">Kunst Ficus</a> <a href="../kunst_guirlande/" title="Kunst Guirlande">Kunst Guirlande</a> <a href="../kunsthaag_elementen/" title="Kunsthaag elementen">Kunsthaag elementen</a> <a href="../uv_planten/" title="UV planten">UV planten</a> <a href="../grote_kunstplanten/" title="Grote kunstplanten">Grote kunstplanten</a></p>
<p class="centre">Copyright 2011 <a href="../index.php">kunstplanten-decoratie.nl</a> | <a href="../contact.php" title="Contact">Contact</a> | <a href="../sitemap.php" title="Sitemap">Sitemap</a></p>
</div></div>
<iframe src="http://www.deco-trade.nl/index.php/kunstplanten/alle-planten.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google comment on it: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34445

Another interesting link from that page is http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2064573/Search-Engines-and-Frames

(sorry, there is too much data on each to copy and paste other than the below summary)

From Google: "Google supports frames and iframes to the extent that it can. Frames can cause problems for search engines because they don't correspond to the conceptual model of the web. In this model, one page displays only one URL. Pages that use frames or iframes display several URLs (one for each frame) within a single page. Google tries to associate framed content with the page containing the frames, but we don't guarantee that we will."

If SEO is key for the page(s) that use iFrames, you may want to re-condiser this approach.